# jQuery callback not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-callback

I have the following code and the callback doesn't seem to work properly. My understanding is that if the username is undefined or blank then the #username-error div should show and the error class should be added to the get added to the username input. Only once all of that is done should the alert get fired. However, when I look in my browser, the error div does not show, and the alert gets triggered. So clearly the class 'error' is getting added, and therefore it's reasonable to suggest that the #username-error div is having the .show() function called upon it but it sure does't look like it. Any help you can give me getting the alert to fire only once the #username-error div has appeared would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='username']").bind("blur", function() {
        validateUsername(myFunction);
    });

    $("input[type='submit']").bind("click", function() {
        validateUsername(myFunction);
    });

    $("#username-error").hide();
    $("#username-success").hide();
});

function myFunction() {
    if ($(".error").length > 0) {
        alert("errors on page");
        return false;
    }
}

function validateUsername(callback) {
    var $username = $("input[name='username']");
    if (typeof $username.val() === "undefined" || $username.val() === "") {
        $("#username-error").show();
        $("#username-success").hide();
        $username.addClass("error");
    } else {
        $("#username-error").hide();
        $("#username-success").show();
        $username.removeClass("error");
    }
    if (callback) {
        callback();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you placing the script? It seems to work for me using CodePen. My guess is it's in the `<head>` tag of your document? If this is the case, then it's running before the inputs are parsed, so the bind calls aren't working properly. Working codepen: http://codepen.io/shigidaMark/pen/oxBzjb. From jQuery: `Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call to .bind() occurs.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a return the button click

```
$("input[type='submit']").bind("click", function() {
    return validateUsername(myFunction);
});
```

and you should return true

```
function myFunction() {
    if ($(".error").length > 0) {
        alert("errors on page");
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
}
```

and add return in the validate method

```
function validateUsername(callback) {
    var $username = $("input[name='username']");
    if (typeof $username.val() === "undefined" || $username.val() === "") {
        $("#username-error").show();
        $("#username-success").hide();
        $username.addClass("error");
    } else {
        $("#username-error").hide();
        $("#username-success").show();
        $username.removeClass("error");
    }
    if (callback) {
        return callback();
    }
```

}

but the use of the callback in this really does not make much sense.